# Is there a way I could filter values using the Model class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, razor, model, querying

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET MVC4 and I have a search/filter form where you can filter on multiple parameters

So this is my controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string page, int? neighborhoodID, int? accommodationType) {
...
}
```

I was thinking. I'm using data annotations and validation for my login/registering by using the Model class.

Is there a way I could filter values using the Model class?

Now I just look at the requested parameters and use them in my linq query to get the filtered records.

Comment: Your question is a little vague.  What's wrong with the way you are doing it now?

Comment: Well I have a function: public static List<Accommodation> GetAccommodationsByNeighborhoodIdAndAccType(int nId, int accType) that queries the database (with the filtered values) and if I would add more values this could get complicated. And I don't know if this is the way to do it.

Comment: why don't you create a `InputModel` and use it as a single parameter? I mean, a class with theses properties and if you need other properties, you can just add new properties and it will work fine.

Comment: I don't understand so I would have this:                       public class InputModel {
    public int NeighborhoodId { get; set; }
    public int AccommodationType { get; set; }
} and how would I filter now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create an `IndexViewModel` class

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public int? NeighbourhoodId { get; set; }
    public int? AccomodationType { get; set; }  
}
```

Then add `@model IndexViewModel` to the top of your view

It seems that `neigbourhoodId` and `accomodationType` come from dropdowns, so map viewModel properties to those dropdowns

and then the controller method will be somehting like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string page, IndexViewModel model) 
{
    // You can use model.NeighbourhoodId and model.AccomodationType the same way you did with parameters
}
```